# Cut out a sequence of files using glob in python

Tags: python, filter, filenames, glob

I have a directory with files like `img-0001.jpg, img-0005.pg, img-0006.jpg, ... , img-xxxx.jpg`.
What I need to do is to get a list with all files starting at `0238`, literally `img-0238.jpg`. The next existing filename is `img-0240.jpg`

Right now I use glob to get all filenames.

```
list_images = glob.glob(path_images + "*.jpg")
```

Thanks in advance

Edit:

-> The last filename is `img-0315.jpg`

Comment: If that's "literally" the file name you want, you don't need a glob. If you want `*0100*.jpg` or perhaps `*01[0-9][0-9].jpg` then ... those are the wildcards.

Comment: I need all from 0238 on

Comment: That seems to directly conflict with what's in your question. Probably [edit] it to show in more detail what files exactly you have, and which of those you want.

Comment: edited and put some additional information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glob doesn't allow regex filtering. But you filter list right after you receive all matching files.
Here is how it would look like using `re`:

```
import re

list_images = [f for f in glob.glob(path_images + "*.jpg") \
    if re.search(r'[1-9]\d{3,}|0[3-9]\d{2,}|02[4-9]\d|023[8-9]\.jpg$', f)]
```

The regular expression with verify that file ends with number with 4 digits bigger or equal `0238`.

You can play around with regular expression using https://regex101.com/

Basically, we check if number is:

- starts with `1` followed by any `3` digits
- or starts with `0[3-9]` followed by any `2` digits
- or starts with `02[4-9]` followed by any `1` digit
- or starts with `023` and followed by either `8` or `9`.

But it's probably would be easier to do simple comparison:

```
list_images = [f for f in glob.glob(path_images + "*.jpg") \
     if f[-8:-4] > "0237" and f[-8:-4] < "0316"]
```

Comment: tried the second solution out, the list_images list is empty

Comment: What's your `path_images` value? make sure it ends with directory separator, make sure that your path in `glog.glob(...)` is valid and returns list of files. Just checked, works perfectly if path is valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify multiple repeated wildcards to match all files whose number is `23[89]` or `2[4-9][0-9]` or `30[0-9]` etc;

```
list_images = []
for pattern in ('023[89]', '02[4-9][0-9]', '030[0-9]', '031[0-5]'):
    list_images.extend(glob.glob(
        os.path.join(path_images, '*{0}.jpg'.format(pattern))))
```

or you can just filter out the ones you don't want.

```
list_images = [x for x in glob.glob(os.path.join(path_images, "*.jpg"))
    if 238 <= int(x[-8:-4]) <= 315]
```

Comment: tried both out, list_images stays empty in both cases

Answer (score 0):

For something like this, you could try the [wcmatch](https://github.com/facelessuser/wcmatch) library. It's a library that aims to enhance file globbing and wildcard matching.

In this example, we enable [brace](https://facelessuser.github.io/wcmatch/glob/#globbrace) expansion and demonstrate the pattern by filtering a list of files:

```
from wcmatch import glob

files = []
# Generate list of files from img-0000.jpg to img-0315.jpg
for x in range(316):
    files.append('path/img-{:04d}.jpg'.format(x))

print(glob.globfilter(files, 'path/img-{0238..0315}.jpg', flags=glob.BRACE))
```

And we get the following output:

```
['path/img-0238.jpg', 'path/img-0239.jpg', 'path/img-0240.jpg', 'path/img-0241.jpg', 'path/img-0242.jpg', 'path/img-0243.jpg', 'path/img-0244.jpg', 'path/img-0245.jpg', 'path/img-0246.jpg', 'path/img-0247.jpg', 'path/img-0248.jpg', 'path/img-0249.jpg', 'path/img-0250.jpg', 'path/img-0251.jpg', 'path/img-0252.jpg', 'path/img-0253.jpg', 'path/img-0254.jpg', 'path/img-0255.jpg', 'path/img-0256.jpg', 'path/img-0257.jpg', 'path/img-0258.jpg', 'path/img-0259.jpg', 'path/img-0260.jpg', 'path/img-0261.jpg', 'path/img-0262.jpg', 'path/img-0263.jpg', 'path/img-0264.jpg', 'path/img-0265.jpg', 'path/img-0266.jpg', 'path/img-0267.jpg', 'path/img-0268.jpg', 'path/img-0269.jpg', 'path/img-0270.jpg', 'path/img-0271.jpg', 'path/img-0272.jpg', 'path/img-0273.jpg', 'path/img-0274.jpg', 'path/img-0275.jpg', 'path/img-0276.jpg', 'path/img-0277.jpg', 'path/img-0278.jpg', 'path/img-0279.jpg', 'path/img-0280.jpg', 'path/img-0281.jpg', 'path/img-0282.jpg', 'path/img-0283.jpg', 'path/img-0284.jpg', 'path/img-0285.jpg', 'path/img-0286.jpg', 'path/img-0287.jpg', 'path/img-0288.jpg', 'path/img-0289.jpg', 'path/img-0290.jpg', 'path/img-0291.jpg', 'path/img-0292.jpg', 'path/img-0293.jpg', 'path/img-0294.jpg', 'path/img-0295.jpg', 'path/img-0296.jpg', 'path/img-0297.jpg', 'path/img-0298.jpg', 'path/img-0299.jpg', 'path/img-0300.jpg', 'path/img-0301.jpg', 'path/img-0302.jpg', 'path/img-0303.jpg', 'path/img-0304.jpg', 'path/img-0305.jpg', 'path/img-0306.jpg', 'path/img-0307.jpg', 'path/img-0308.jpg', 'path/img-0309.jpg', 'path/img-0310.jpg', 'path/img-0311.jpg', 'path/img-0312.jpg', 'path/img-0313.jpg', 'path/img-0314.jpg', 'path/img-0315.jpg']
```

So, we could apply this to a file search:

```
from wcmatch import glob

list_images = glob.glob('path/img-{0238..0315}.jpg', flags=glob.BRACE)
```

In this example, we've hard coded the path, but in your example, make sure `path_images` has a trailing `/` so that the pattern is constructed correctly. Others have suggested this might be an issue. Print out your pattern to confirm the pattern is correct.